# Connecting Ethernet to PIC18F97J60

Tags: microcontroller, microchip, poe

I am currently working on my diploma thesis and since circuit construction is not the main topic, I am unfortunately not making any progress. I would like to connect the PIC18F97J60-IPT with PoE. I have assembled the PoE splitter from data sheets. My question now is how do I connect the PIC18 to the Pulse Transformer, as the PIC only has 4 pins (73,74, 77, 78) but the [H6062NL](https://productfinder.pulseelectronics.com/api/open/part-attachments/datasheet/H6062NL) has 8 pins?

[image: Schematics]

Comment: Figure 19-2 in the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/39762f.pdf) is fairly clear about this. You only need two of the four transformers in the H6062NL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gigabit ethernet uses 4 pairs, 10/100 ethernet uses just 2 pairs.

You transformer is designed for the former, whilst the phy is the latter.

I believe you just need to connect the two pairs for 10/100, and all should be good.